# how to add custom fee/extra fee in total by api?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, quote

I want to add an additional charge in the order total by Api. when a customer needs that.
I added an additional amount by following this link https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-pricefee-order-total-magento2/.
Can someone help me how to add the amount by checking the flag. customer needs that through Rest Api.

Comment: You need to add the custom parameters into the endpoint. you can do this by extending the order API and adding in the new fee parameter

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a rule on shopping cart. Easy and native way of doing. Endless possibilities.

I found this nice tutorial from Mageplaza: https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-2-extra-fee-configuration.html

Hope that helps my friend.

Comment: thank you . but i want to add a custom amount by api.